# What does it mean to renormalize an effective field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, renormalization, regularization, effective-field-theory

This is in reference to slide 19 of this [talk](http://cosmology.lbl.gov/talks/Pajer_13.pdf)

"*As always in Effective Field Theory, the theory becomes predictive when there are more observables than parameters*"

- Can one explain what this exactly means? May be if you can refer me to examples or literature where this is explained?
- In this case it seems that this translates into having 2 fields ($\delta$ and $v$) and hence 3 2-point functions to regularize but one seems to have only two counterterms. Then how does this make sense?

Isn't the quoted line basically mean that there is a meaningful interpretation of the scenario with having more correlations to regularize than counter-terms? What is the meaning?

Comment: In the bottom-up approach to EFT you add a bunch of operators to the Lagrangian, not knowing their precise (dimensionless) coefficients. Suppose you add $N$ terms, then clearly you need to fix these $N$ c-numbers by matching with data. If you have more than $N$ measurements, you can then give a prediction for the $N+1$st, $N+2$nd, ... measurements.

Comment: @Vibert The confusion is this - as I said in that theory there are 3 2-point functions to be regularized but there are 2 countertrms available. Now the value of counterterm is determined by requirement of cancelling the poles of the 2-point functions. Now if both the counterterms are getting determined by asking regularity of 1 or 2 of the correlation functions then what happens to the 3rd correlation? - it remains unregularized! I can't be predictive unless all the correlation functions are regularized - right?

Comment: reread @Vilbert . For the loose term you will use real data to fix it by fitting the theory prediction to the value of the data. Then you have a theory that could predict further physical results to be checked by data.

Comment: @anna v What do you mean by the "theory prediction"? The theory prediction is a divergent/ill-defined correlation function - I would think that one needs to first choose counterterms such that the 1/epsilon poles are cancelled and then one can compare to the experiment. BUT if one has more correlations to regularize then counterterms then what is the interpretation? Is one saying that one will choose a different set of counterterm values to regularize each of the correlations?

Comment: @anna v I would think that the issue is that one can't compare to experiment unless one has cancelled the poles by counterterms. But when one has more correlations to regularize than counterms (As seems generic to any effective field theory) then what does one do? - say you exhausted both your counterterms to regularize $<AA>$ and $<BB>$ but it doesn't guarantee that $<AB>$ will now be regular - so I would guess that one needs to choose a different set of counterterms for each correlation to ensure that each is regular?

Comment: I hope a theorist answers your question as I think that once you have taken care of the poles the correlations follow suit but it is just a hand wave.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken completely you can assume that $\langle A B \rangle = 0$. Why? Well, collect all bilinear terms in $A,B$ in the Lagrangian, so you get a Lagrangian of the form $L = \phi_a K_{ab} \phi_b$+higher order terms, and here $\phi = (A,B).$ Then you *define* the fields $A',B'$ as the eigenvectors of $K$. It would be stupid to quantize a theory with non-diagonal two-point functions (propagators).

Comment: @Vibert Firstly the theory that the author describes in the the slides is a classical field theory and one is renormalizing that. Secondly in this theory the perturbation is about an interacting solution already and hence $<AB>$ non-zero to start-off with.Here one is using a series solution for an interacting theory and using that series solution to calculate the correlations.The series solution is of an interacting theory.

Comment: @Vibert  Thirdly the issue can come even at the level of just $<AA>$ OR $<BB>$ because any one of these correlators can have double poles in this theory - then both the counterterms get exhausted in regularizing any one of the correlations and hence the other remains unphysical. Hence my proposal as to if it makes sense to choose a different set of values of counterterms for each correlation to make them regular by cancelling its poles.

Answer (score 5):

Theories like QED, where one has a finite number of relevant operators are very rare. Many important predictions are performed by means of effective theories (Please see the following reviews by: [Aneesh V. Manohar](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9606222) and [Scherer and Schindler](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0505265)). It is sometimes said that that since these theories are nonrenormalizable,  then any loop correction beyond the tree level is not useful because we can actually have an infinite numbers of free parameters that can  fit the theory to any data that we have.

However, Consider for example chiral perturbation theory which describes the low energy degrees of freedom of QCD (with 3 flavors):

$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{4} f_{\pi}^2\partial_{\mu}U^{\dagger}\partial_{\mu}U + ...$$

($U \in SU(3)$ is generated by the meson fields). Here, one loop corrections give rise to 8 counterterms whose coefficients can be estimated from various processes. There is evidence for improvement in the precision with respect to the tree level computation.

The improved predictions can be explained as follows: Even though the theory is not renormalizable in the usual sense, but if we restrict the
Lagrangian to terms with less than a given number of derivatives, and a given number of loops, then, there is a finite number of counterterms. The example mentioned above corresponds to terms with up to 4 derivatives. The same terms of order 4 also serve as counterterms needed to renormalize the one loop contribution of the terms with up to 2 derivatives. Thus, if we limit ourselves low energy processes, we need only a finite number of counterterms. In other words up to a given energy scale, we have control on the counterterms

In the example of chiral perturbation theory, we know that it is a low energy effective theory, thus we know that we should stop at some level of the number of derivatives (or momenta).

This procedure is known as approximate renormalizability, in contrast
to the "exact" renormalizability present in QED, where any energy scale can be reached.  Actually, this exact renormalizability is not of much practical use, since QED itself is not valid to very high energies (other interactions become important).

Thus given that we want to work up to some energy scale, we can treat the effective field theory as a renormalizable theory and perform  loop expansions which generate counterterms with no higher scale.

The question is how can we know where to stop. The answer lies in our knowledge of the degrees of freedom outside the theory. For example, the Fermi theory of weak interactions (which includes an effective four fermion term) gives good predictions for beta decays up to energies of the order of magnitude of the mass of the $W$-boson which is integrated out in the Fermi theory.

This "relaxation" of the renormalizability requirements does not mean
that we have an infinite number of effective theories at our disposal.
Extra structures are needed to create the property of approximate renormalizability. For example, chiral perturbation theory stems from the origin of pions as the Goldstone bosons of the chiral symmetry breaking.

A major factor which can spoil the approximate renormalizability are anomalies. If we try to gauge an anomalous symmetry, then we loose control on the number of derivatives in the counterterms. Moreover, if we gauge only anomaly free subgroups, then the counterterms will be gauge invariant up to total derivatives in the Lagrangian, and we have Ward identities to each scale.

Comment: Its been more than an year now, I know, but I wasn't around when you posted this. Regarding that sentence ''_we can actually have an infinite numbers of free parameters that can fit the theory to any data that we have_'', I feel tempted to agree, because typically with these eff. Lagrangians, sometimes, we bend over backwards to fit parameters. But I have a question, in case you feel tempted to respond. Suppose, we have one model based on LO Lagrangian, with the parameters fit. Next, we go to NLO, or maybe NNLO, naturally we would need extra parameter fits. Will both predict the same Physics?

Comment: @ New_new_newbie It may happen that some process (like photon-photon scattering in QED) does not exist at the tree level approximation, then you can say that radiative corrections predict new physics. But apart from  that, the control of  the quantum corrections is mainly required  to ensure that these corrections will not spoil the leading order.

Comment: @DavidBarMosche - Well, I agree with all of that, but QED is still comparatively well-controlled as against any eff. Lag. in low-energy QCD, or more specifically, in hadrodynamics. We may use e.g. chiral invariance to write down an LO Lag for hadron-hadron interactions, and then fit the free parameters to some constraints. Someone else may go to NLO and then fit. I'm curious whether we are improving at all by going beyond LO, if one is resorting to phenomenological fitting, because I think such a procedure implies that both L's are capable of reproducing what we fitted to! (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) But overall, we expect NLO to be richer than LO, since there is no reason why an NLO prediction to be smaller than LO, unlike the QED case. Even in phenomenology, the fitted parameters are typically larger then 1. Do you have any insights about what's going on here? (and thanks for responding :) )